# Can't pass an Object or String from FragmentActivity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I need to pass an Object from my FragmentActivity to my Fragments . I have this code for try to pass a String from the FragmentActivity but I get NullPointerException when I try to get in the Fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Descripcion f2= new Descripcion();
    bundle.putString("lugar", lugar.getDescripcionLugar());
    //bundle.putSerializable("lugar", lugar);       
    f2.setArguments(bundle);        
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.principal, f2).commit();
```

In the Fragment I have ...

```
    private String des; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    des=getArguments().getString("lugar"); // Here I get NullPointerException       
}
```

How Can I pass a String or an Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First fragment:

```
            Intent firstpage = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    NavigationActivity.class);

            // String message = "keels";

            if (name == "Keels Super") {
                int id1 = 1;
                firstpage.putExtra("message", id1);
            }
```

Second fragment Activity:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        String result = extras.getString("message");
        int res = extras.getInt("message");
        System.out.println("yeah" + result);
```